# Spring Initializr error "Could not connect to the server. Please check your server"

Tags: java, spring, web, initializr

When I try to create a Springboot project from https://start.spring.io/. I am getting this error
"Could not connect to the server. Please check your server". Downloading of project artifacts stops.
[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTitu.png)